# How to add Heatmap to TileView Library (moagrius)?

Tags: android, heatmap

Library Used: https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/

I am using a single image of size 1825 * 1650 in order to display my floorplan inside tile view like this. I have added markers on certain points (x,y) in my image. It works great. But now how can I add heatmap functionality on to this tiled view. Can anyone please help?

```
tileView = new TileView(this);
findViewById(R.id.main_tile_layout)).addView(tileView);
tileView.setId(R.id.tile_view);
tileView.setSize(1825, 1650);
tileView.setScale(0,2);
tileView.addDetailLevel( 1.000f, "tiles/floorplan_0/125/%d_%d.png");
```

This is my activity layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_tile_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used that library version 2, so I'm not sure my information is still correct in version 3.

Anyhow, if the heatmap functionality is what I expected, then it should be possible to implement using `drawPath()` method. I know that library has limited documentation, but what it does is that it draws path on the canvas of the tileview.

Here is a sample of my code using `drawPath()` method. (in Kotlin)

```
val range = CompositePathView.DrawablePath()
range.paint = rangePaint
range.path = Path()
range.path.addCircle(x, y, (distance * pixelsPerMeter), Path.Direction.CW )
tileView.drawPath(range)
```

This [page](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/tree/version-2.7.7) should help. It is version 2.7.7 of that library and search for `drawPath`.

Comment: Yes i have used drawpath in order to draw path between 2 markers. But how can I create heatmap effect like https://i.stack.imgur.com/rczhi.png?

Comment: @androidbash Well, I'm not sure it can be done in THAT quality with all that gradient. But I'm sure it can be done with closed polygonal path to draw [this](https://www.espatial.com/wp-content/uploads/Hot-Spot-Heat-Map-2.jpg) quality.

Comment: This is enough for me. Can you tell me how i can do it for set of points? Is the code posted is enough?

Comment: @androidbash That code is for drawing a circle. Why don't you refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) page for more about Path.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Let me try now and see how i can make it look like heatmap. But you are sure right (https://www.espatial.com/wp-content/uploads/Hot-Spot-Heat-Map-2.jpg) we can reach this quality